# ¿Como mostrar nombres de una lista en un MessageBox?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo el siguiente problema: Estoy intentando mostrar los nombres guardados en una lista en un MessageBox pero los nombres me salen en la parte de arriba del mismo y no en el centro donde quiero que estén. Adjunto foto.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven, los nombres Salmon Salmon que son insertados por el usuario en el textBox "nombre" de más arriba y luego pasados al DataGridView de abajo cuando se hace click en el botón "agregar producto" me salen en la parte de arriba del MessageBox y no en el centro como yo quiero.

Acá el código:

```
 // CALCULA EL VALOR TOTAL DE LA MESA E IMPRIME EL TICKET
    private void btnTicket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Pagos.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            total += double.Parse(Pagos.Rows[i].Cells["celdaSubtotal"].Value.ToString());
        }

        etiquetaTotalNum.Text = total.ToString();
        total = 0;

        var lista = new List<string>();

        string nombre = "";
        string mesa = this.numMesa.Trim();
        var consultaProductos = "Select nombre from Productos where mesa = @mesa";
        using (var comd = new SQLiteCommand(consultaProductos, conexion)
        {
            Parameters =
            {
            new SQLiteParameter("@mesa", mesa)
            }
        })
        {
            using (var read = comd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (read.Read())
                {
                    lista.Add(read.GetString(read.GetOrdinal("nombre")));
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (String nombresProducto in lista)
        {
            nombre += nombresProducto + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Nombre de Producto: ", nombre);



    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba poniendo los textos al revés

```
MessageBox.Show(nombre, "Nombre de Producto: ");
```

Te recomiendo usar este mensaje para que sea más atractivo el mensaje:

```
MessageBox.Show(nombre, "Nombre de Producto: ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

Aquí esta la [documentación del MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.110).aspx)

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Me corrigió el error ... En realidad lo que necesito es que TODO me aparezca en el medio del MessageBox ... osea, Nombre de producto: xxxxx ... y luego le quiero poner algunos datos más como Precio de cada producto, etc ... que me recomendas ?

Comment: Podes hacer algo como esto:                                                                  string cadena = "";
foreach (String producto in lista)
        {
     cadena += "Nombre del Producto: " + producto["nombre"] + Environment.NewLine;
            cadena += Precio del Producto: " + producto["nombre"] + Environment.NewLine;
     cadena += "Cantidad: " + producto["cantidad"] + Environment.NewLine;
            cadena += "------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Nombre de Producto: ", cadena);

Comment: Unicamente que en la lista tienen que estar todos los datos, no solo el nombre del producto